# Accessing `self` from thread target

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

According to a number of sources, including [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/660961/2988730), passing a runnable as the `target` parameter in [`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) (with or without `args` and `kwargs`) is preferable to extending the `Thread` class.

If I create a runnable, how can I pass the thread it is running on as `self` to it without extending the `Thread` class? For example, the following would work fine:

```
class MyTask(Thread):
    def run(self):
        print(self.name)
MyTask().start()
```

However, I can't see a good way to get this version to work:

```
def my_task(t):
    print(t.name)
Thread(target=my_task, args=(), kwargs={}).start()
```

This question is a followup to [Python - How can I implement a 'stoppable' thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47912701/2988730), which I answered, but possibly incompletely.

**Update**

I've thought of a hack to do this using [`current_thread()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.current_thread):

```
def my_task():
    print(current_thread().name)
Thread(target=my_task).start()
```

Problem: calling a function to get a parameter that should ideally be passed in.

**Update #2**

I have found an even hackier solution that makes `current_thread` seem much more attractive:

```
class ThreadWithSelf(Thread):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        args = kwargs.get('args', ())
        args = (self,) + tuple(args)
        kwargs[args] = args
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
ThreadWithSelf(target=my_task).start()
```

Besides being incredibly ugly (e.g. by *forcing* the user to use keywords only, even if that is the recommended way in the documentation), this completely defeats the purpose of not extending `Thread`.

**Update #3**

Another ridiculous (and unsafe) solution: to pass in a mutable object via `args` and to update it afterwards:

```
def my_task(t):
    print(t[0].name)
container = []
t = Thread(target=my_task, args=(container,))
container[0] = t
t.start()
```

To avoid synchronization issues, you could kick it up a notch and implement another layer of ridiculousness:

```
 def my_task(t, i):
     print(t[i].name)
 container = []
 container[0] = Thread(target=my_task, args=(container, 0))
 container[1] = Thread(target=my_task, args=(container, 1))
 for t in container:
     t.start()
```

I am still looking for a legitimate answer.

Comment: I was just about to answer using `current_thread()`. Why does that not work for you? I don't quite understand the "problem" you describe.

Comment: @bnaecker. I would like to be able to pass in the parameter when the task is called by the thread. I can't seem to get around the chicken or the egg problem here, where the thread has to exist to be able to be present in `args`.

Comment: What parameter are you trying to pass? Can it not be passed using either the `args` or `kwargs` keywords to the `Thread` constructor?

Comment: In your function `my_task`, the `t` parameter is not the thread itself. `t` could take its value from the `args` argument, but you gave none.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE. It could, but you can't pass the object you are constructing to its own constructor. Well, you can and do, but I can't make it appear in an argument other than `self`. That is the problem I am trying to overcome. I don't know how to pass in `t` effectively.

Comment: @bnaecker. I want the thread itself to be an argument to run, as it would be if I extended the class.

Comment: As you said, you can't pass the thread object as an argument to the target. I don't see why it's hacky at all to use `current_thread()`. This is exactly what it's designed for. Or just extend `Thread`, that seems perfectly legitimate to me too. You want to add functionality to a class, which is a pretty good operational definition of a subclass.

Comment: @bnaecker. I just tested my one real concern with `current_thread`: https://ideone.com/U7W4ph. If you would like to post an answer, that would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like your goal is to get access to the thread currently executing a task from within the task itself. You can't add the thread as an argument to the `threading.Thread` constructor, because it's not yet constructed. I think there are two real options.

1. If your task runs many times, potentially on many different threads, I think the best option is to use [`threading.current_thread()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html?highlight=current_thread#threading.current_thread) from within the task. This gives you access directly to the thread object, with which you can do whatever you want. This seems to be exactly the kind of use-case this function was designed for.
2. On the other hand, if your goal is implement a thread with some special characteristics, the natural choice is to subclass `threading.Thread`, implementing whatever extended behavior you wish.

Also, as you noted in your comment, `insinstance(current_thread(), ThreadSubclass)` will return `True`, meaning you can use both options and be assured that your task will have access to whatever extra behavior you've implemented in your subclass.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most readable answer here is: use `current_thread()`. You can use various weird ways to pass the thread as a parameter, but there's no good reason for that. Calling `current_thread()` is the standard approach which is shorter than all the alternatives and will not confuse other developers. Don't try to overthink/overengineer this:

```
def runnable():
    thread = threading.current_thread()

Thread(target=runnable).start()
```

If you want to hide it a bit and change for aesthetic reasons, you can try:

```
def with_current_thread(f):
    return f(threading.current_thread())

@with_current_thread
def runnable(thread):
    print(thread.name)

Thread(target=runnable).start()
```

If this is not good enough, you may get better answers by describing why you think the parameter passing is better / more correct for your use case.

Comment: Nice use of decorator. Hadn't thought of that.

Comment: As a fan of the film Idiocracy, I liked it better before the edit.